# Chrome spell checker not displaying the errors when showing the saved data

Tags: google-chrome

I am using chrome spell checker in one of my application. On page load the saved data will be displayed. But the error words are not underlined until we edit or type on the controls. 
On showing the saved data[image]

Here the textbox contains the wrong words but they are not underlined by chrome as error. But on editing the textbox showing the words as errors

[image]